# How to find a business name using only the address with Google Place Search API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

There is a Five Guys restaurant at 1628 Shore Pkwy, Brooklyn, NY 11214. But if make the following request:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=1628+Shore+Pkwy,+Brooklyn,+NY+1214&inputtype=textquery&fields=name,formatted_address,place_id,geometry/location,types&key=XXXXX`

I get only data about the location:

```
{
   "candidates" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "1628 Shore Pkwy, Brooklyn, NY 11214, EUA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.59517870000001,
               "lng" : -74.0002082
            }
         },
         "name" : "1628 Shore Pkwy",
         "place_id" : "ChIJaR1SsaZFwokRx_mn6wlXDSw",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I can only get the Five Guys data if I add some information related to the establishment in the query. For example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=1628+Shore+Pkwy+Brooklyn+NY+1214+five&inputtype=textquery&fields=name,formatted_address,place_id,geometry/location,types&key=XXXXX
```

gives me what I want:

```
{
   "candidates" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "1628 Shore Pkwy, Brooklyn, NY 11214, United States",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.5952363,
               "lng" : -74.0002255
            }
         },
         "name" : "Five Guys",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ3XR8AlNbwokRafmD4huXlzQ",
         "types" : [
            "meal_takeaway",
            "restaurant",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The problem is I won't have related information for the queries I want to do, only the address. How to work around that?

Comment: You probably need to make two requests: 1. geocode the address to get the coordinates (or use your existing query to get the coordinates). 2. query the places api using [`nearbysearch`](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) with a small distance and those coordinates.

Comment: The Google Maps Javascript API Places library returns the name "Five Guys" for that query (but it looks like you need the web service).  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z830yLgn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you replace "+five" with "+name", it seems to work in the general case.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=1628+Shore+Pkwy+Brooklyn+NY+1214+name&inputtype=textquery&fields=name,formatted_address,place_id,geometry/location,types&key=XXXXX
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).